# How to get max value of a alphanumeric string in column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

ID:

```
20190126T153450495Ztest1@test1.com
20190126T155922394Ztest2@test2.com
20190126T164741292Ztest3@test3.com
20190126T160108969Ztest4@test4.com
20190205T000624869Ztest5@test5.com
```

How do I get the the maximum value in the `ID` column simply based on the datetimestamps?

Max value in this case would be:

`20190205T000624869Ztest5@test5.com`

If it helps the dtype on this column is `object`

Comment: Simplest way is to use `sorted` built-in function. `sorted(data, reverse=True)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get first `18` values, convert to `datetime`s and get index of maximal value, last select by [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.at.html) or `loc`:

```
idx = pd.to_datetime(df['ID'].str[:18], format='%Y%m%dT%H%M%S%f').idxmax()

a = df.at[idx, 'ID']
#similar
#a = df.loc[idx, 'ID']
print (a)
20190205T000624869Ztest5@test5.com
```

Another solution with [`argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html):

```
idx = df['ID'].str[:18].argsort().idxmax()

a = df.at[idx, 'ID']
```